# Python logging more overview in logfile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, logging, error-logging

In my example, I've created a complete debug output of my test via logging. Everything works and I hand this over to a file.

**A few questions:**

- Is it possible to write a File Pro test?
- Is there a possibility if a.) Is not possible to make the Debug Log Pro test clearer?

i used for the first Info https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

**task**

- Single executed test either from the format mr faster and better log in the debug log
- Individual test after each test run a separate file

**used modules**

```
import testcore
from testcore.control.ssh import SSH
import unittest
from test import support
import logging
import os
```

**used Debug information**

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='%(asctime)s:%(created)f:%(levelno)s:%(message)s:%(process)d')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this problem and the questions myself. I now used the logging package, and that appropriate handling per test case.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html